# How does "add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin * " work

Tags: cors

Does it mean our nginx server can access any other server's resources? Or does it mean other any servers can access our nginx server's resources?
I know it's related to Cross Origin Resource Sharing. But not sure what Origin is meant in this case.

Comment: it's to do with access to resources from front end javascript (i.e a browser) from a domain (origin) that isn't yours - it's probably better explained in some [documenation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) I found when searching for "what is CORS"